# Routing error refers to a namespace that no longer exists

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2013 with latest update and ASP.NET MVC5 + latest Web.API package.

I am receiving this error:

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Example'...
>
> The request for 'Feeds' has found the following matching controllers:
> OldNamespace.Controllers.ExampleController and NewNamespace.Controllers.ExampleController

Previously in my project I had a namespace called "OldNamespace.Controllers" and I did a Find and Replace in Files with "NewNamespace.Controllers".  Following find and replace I Cleaned the solution, Rebuilt, deleted ASP.NET Temporary Files and also did a full text search of the project's directories for any references to "OldNamespace" and none were found.  Finally I searched the file system for any DLLs named "OldNamespace..." and deleted them, deleted the bin and obj directories and restarted the PC.

Yet this error still occurs.

Comment: I would try doing a clean build and verify the bin folder is empty. If that doesn't work, I would try restarting the PC.

Comment: @Hexxagonal I should have mentioned that I actually did those both as well...  I will update the question.

Comment: I think I am going to generalize the question (at least the title) as I doubt this problem is ASP.NET MVC related.

Comment: You realize, of course, that this is cause for celebration. Finally, an artificial intelligence has been created which can travel back in time and locate namespaces which used to exist, but which no longer _do_ exist. This is marvelous.

Comment: Or, the namespace actually _does_ exist somewhere, and you just don't yet know _where_.

Comment: What happens if you commit your changes so that another dev can get the latest version and try to build the solution?

Comment: @dustinmoris That's a great idea I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Check for these possible cases

Try ReplaceAll OldNamespace with NewNamespace

If the problem still persists as a workaround add the namespace in the routeconfig though not the exact solution

public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces:new string[]
            {
                "OldNamespace"
            }
        );
    }
}
```